# After dismissing the app ,some times later it still shows My app in recent app list

Tags: android, background-service, android-recents

My app do not have any background services . But when i dismiss it from my recent app list and after some time if I check recent app list it still present in it without opening it again. So , how can I prevent this?

Comment: This happens to me with all Apps. Seems like Android itself is a bit buggy...

Comment: [read this](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/17/lollipops-app-switcher-has-a-bug-that-shows-random-cards-after-youve-cleared-them-all/)